# How to match and remove a string of characters in a pattern

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I am trying to remove a constant string of characters that match a pattern.  I can match the pattern via awk,  is there a combination of awk and sed or perhaps just awk that can delete the string in place?

Example:

I need to match the 14th, 15th and 16th "|" symbol and delete the content in between.

**Before**:

```
00000000,003377fdh,,BLUE,YELLOW,ORANGE,UANGTANG,||57000000|1250000000|2|ramp|CAR|||||||24000|11000|apples,12-15-2017
```

**After:**

```
00000000,003377fdh,,BLUE,YELLOW,ORANGE,UANGTANG,||57000000|1250000000|2|ramp|CAR||||||,12-15-2017
```

Comment: What happened to "apples"?

Comment: how do you like them apples?

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: wrt `is there a combination of awk and sed` - no. You never need sed when you're using awk since awk can do anything that sed can do.

Comment: You said, "I need to match the 14th, 15th and 16th "|" symbol and delete the content in between.", well there are only 15 occurrences of `|` in your **Before:** example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F '|' -v 'OFS=|' '{$13 = $16; NF -= 3; print}' file
```

or

```
perl -F'\|' -ne 'splice(@F, 12, 3); print join("|", @F)' file
```

Comment: The effect of decrementing NF is undefined behavior per POSIX so YYMV...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sed too

```
sed -E 's/(([^|]*\|){3})//5' infile
```